# Is there a way of reverting to a previous save?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is actually an old problem for me that goes back to the 1.8 and 1.9 versions of Minecraft.

What happened was I logged into 1.9 and changed many of my old command blocks to the newer type.  The only problem was at the time I only had the 1.8 version of WorldEdit.  So I opened my now 1.9 world in 1.8.  This caused all the chunks with the new command blocks to be replaced with random new chunks, deleting all my command blocks.

I'm pretty good with command blocks but losing quite a few hours of work is a real pain in the neck.

It's  been a couple months since then and I only thought of fixing it now.  I find it unlikely, but I,d like to know if there is some way to revert back to a previous save in Minecraft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The save files in Minecraft do not contain information to restore it to a previous state, nor does it automatically generate backups.

If you happen to have put the save files in Dropbox, you can look for previous versions of it due to Dropbox maintaining something similar to a versioning-control system for your files.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is make a program that automaticlly backups the world folder.
I made a small program in python that backups the world every 5 minutes to a zip file.

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import shutil

f = 'path/to/the/world/folder/<name>'  # folder to zip
z = 'path/to/make/the/backup/<name>'  # ziped folder

while True:
    sleep(300)  # new backup every 5 minutes (that time is measured in seconds so feel free to adjust it)
    shutil.make_archive(z, 'zip', f)
    print(f"New Backup made at: {datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}")
```

This makes a backup and replaces the previous backup so you don't end up filling your hard drive with lots of unnecessary files.

Comment: Not sure why this uses a program....